# std multiset insert and keep length fixed

Tags: c++, stdset

I am interested in inserting elements in a std::multiset but I would like to keep the set fixed length. Every time an element is  inserted, the last element will be removed. I came up with the following solution

```
int main(){
       std::multiset<std::pair<double, int>> ms;
       for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
              ms.insert(std::pair<double, int>(double(rand())/RAND_MAX, i));
      }
      ms.insert(std::pair<double, int>(0.5, 10));
      ms.erase(--ms.end());
      for(auto el : ms){std::cout<<el.first<<"\t"<<el.second<<std::endl;}
return 0;
}
```

I will be doing something similar to this many times in my code on sets of a size in the order of 1000 elements. Is there a more performant way of doing this? I am worried that the erase will cause memory reallocation and slow down the code.

Comment: Do you use a `std::multiset` because you need to keep the container sorted?

Comment: In other words: is it important that the *last* element is erased? Or can it be any element?

Comment: I was under the impression that std::set can't handle the case in which 2 elements are the same so to avoid this I used multisite.

I will always have to remove the last element.

Comment: Yes, a `std::set`'s elements are unique, while a `std::multiset`'s elements are not. But both are sorted.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16220234/5717589) may be of some interest to you. It's a comparison of performance of a priority queue and a multiset.